# Finding the double derivative in the distributional sense

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-operators

I want to find $u''$ in the distributional sense, where $u(x) = (1+|x|)^{-2}$
But I am very confused on how to do it.

I think this is right:
$\langle u'', \varphi \rangle = \langle u',\varphi ' \rangle = \langle u, \varphi ''\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1+|x|)^2 \varphi''(x)\ dx $
But I am very lost on how to continue from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First of all you already defined / found the distributional double derivative.  The point is that it has a simpler expression, involving $\varphi$ instead of $\varphi''$. For this integrate by parts on $[0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0]$ separately, you'll find a smooth derivative except for a jump discontinuity at $0$. Integrate by parts one more time, the boundary terms will give one "Dirac delta" term.

Comment: You forgot a minus sign for $\langle u',\varphi'\rangle$ which is compensated by another missing minus.